# How do you solve $z^4 = 2(1+i\sqrt{3})$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Solve $z^4 = 2(1+i\sqrt{3})$ in the form $r(\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha)$ where $r>0$ and $0\le\alpha<2\pi$

I know you have to find $\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{1})=\frac{\pi}{3}$ and that is $\alpha$? I am not really sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: hint: $1+i\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{1^2+\sqrt{3}^2}\left(\frac 12+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}2\right)=2\,e^{i\pi/3}$

Comment: One huge contributor to the community recently answered a question that described the process of solving this kind of problems. I can't remember who it was. Hopefully someone will know what I'm talking about and provide the link to that answer. Despite this I'm sure there are other similar questions here and this should probably be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: $z^4=4(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt3}{2})$

Comment: $z=\sqrt2(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt3}{2})$

Comment: The $\sqrt{2}$ is right but you have to consider the different roots of $e^{i\pi/3}$ (the four roots $e^{(i\pi/3+2k\pi i)/4}$ !)

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: Replace for example $k$ by $-1,0,1,2$ to get $e^{i\pi/{12}-\pi i/2},\ e^{i\pi/{12}},\cdots$ (that you may write in trigonometric form if you prefer)

Comment: $z = \sqrt2(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$ = $cos\alpha + isin\alpha = e^{i\alpha}$

Comment: Well that was wrong earlier and remains wrong :-). $z=\sqrt{2}\left(\cos(\pi/12)+i\sin(\pi/12)\right)$ and so on (the angle has to be divided by $4$, see DonAntonio's answer)

Comment: @maxmitch Do you understand the goal of this question? Meaning, do you understand the two ways to represent $z$? One is the "cartesian" coordinates for $z$ and the other is "trigonometric". Euler's identity helps you perform this transformation because taking the 4th root of $z$ is ugly when you don't have it in the "complex exponential" form (the $e^{i\alpha}$ stuff).

Comment: I understand that you are supposed to find the modulus and the argument. But I don't understand the steps to find the modulus. And I don't know what to do once you have found them both...

Comment: Try the easier problem where we want to transform $z = 2(1 + i\sqrt{3})$ into its trigonometric form instead of $z^4 = 2(1 + i\sqrt{3})$. If you can do that then you can do one of the main steps for your original problem. You should be able to do the easier problem by just rereading the definitions carefully and drawing it on paper.

Comment: You got $z^4=4\,e^{i\pi/3+2k\pi i}$ (since adding $2\pi$ should change nothing). From this deduce that $z=\sqrt{2}e^{(i\pi/3+2k\pi i)/4}=\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/{12}+k\pi i/2}=\sqrt{2}(\cos(\pi/12+k\pi/2)+i\sin(\pi/12+k\pi/2))$

Comment: Where did he claim to understand the equivalence:
$z^4 = 4e^{i\pi/3}$
?
I really think he needs to take this slower and that the existing answers aren't of much help to him. But perhaps it's the wrong forum too.

Comment: @roliu (if you are talking to me) : he didn't say that he didn't know them either (and he speaks of modulus and argument). That's why there is a discussion... (sorry I have to go...)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni He knows that the exponential form for a complex number is composed of two parts the "modulus" and the "argument". He doesn't seem to know how those are defined (hence why I suggested he reread the definitions carefully). How would he understand that equivalence without that knowledge? And you are right about him not claiming that he didn't know it. But uh I haven't claimed to not know the proof for Fermat's Last Theorem. Valid to suggest that I do know it? Whatever, separate argument.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding square roots of $\sqrt 3 +3i$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148871/finding-square-roots-of-sqrt-3-3i)

Comment: Can you explain how to go from V(a+ib) to $Re^{i\alpha}$?

Comment: Does V=R? and $\alpha$= the argument?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192742/how-to-solve-x3-1/192743#192743

Comment: This detailed explanation may help you too ['Trigonometric Form of Complex Numbers'](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/TrigonometricForm.shtml). Once you get a trigonometric form (ignoring the modulus $R$) $\cos(\alpha)+i\sin(\alpha)$ you may rewrite it as $e^{i\alpha}$ this is [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) (you may consider this exponential form a 'shortcut' if you want with the advantage that the usual formulas for exponentials apply).

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187786/how-to-compute-sqrti-1/187803#187803). Do not forget to up vote the answers that you benefit from them.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$(1)\;\;\;w:=2+2\sqrt 3\,i\implies |w|=\sqrt{4+12}=4\;,\;\;\arg w=\arctan\frac{2\sqrt 3}{2}=\frac{\pi}{3}\;\implies$$

$$(2)\;\;z^4=\left(re^{i\phi}\right)^4=w=4e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}+2k\pi i}\implies z_k=4^{1/4}e^{\frac{\pi i}{12}(1+2k)}\;,\;\;k=0,1,2,3\; (\text{why only these?})$$

Answer (score 1):

$$cos(\alpha)+isin(\alpha)=e^{i\alpha}$$
$$z^{4}=re^{i\alpha}\implies z=(r)^{1/4}e^{i\alpha/4}=r^{1/4}[cos(\alpha /4)+isin(\alpha/4)]$$

Here r=4 and $\alpha=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$