# Minimal polynomial of the root of algebraic number

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have obtained the minimal polynomial of $9-4\sqrt{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ by algebraic operations:

$$ (x-9)^2-32 = x^2-18x+49.$$

I wonder how to calculate the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{9-4\sqrt{2}}$ with the help of this sub-result? Or is there a smarter way to do this (not necessarily algorithmic)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $x = 9 - 4\sqrt{2}$ satisfies $x^2 - 18x + 49 = 0$, your number $y = \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{9 - 4\sqrt{2}}$ satisfies $y^4 - 18y^2 + 49 = 0$. This could be your minimal polynomial, but the polynomial factorizes as $$y^4 - 18y^2 + 49 = (y^2 + 2y - 7)(y^2 - 2y - 7).$$ Since the product is zero if and only if at least one of them is zero, we get that either $y^2 + 2y - 7 = 0$ or $y^2 - 2y - 7 = 0$. Since the minimal polynomial must have degree at least $2$, one of those must be your minimal polynomial. (In this case it is the latter, $y^2 - 2y - 7$.)

Answer (score 9):

Your number will satisfy $x^4-18x^2+49=0$, and that will be minimal unless your number is already in ${\bf Q}(\sqrt2)$, which it is, since $(1-2\sqrt2)^2=9-4\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 4):

$\rm x^4-18\,x^2+49\:$ will be the minimal polynomial, unless $\rm\:\sqrt{9-4\sqrt{2}}\:$ denests to $\rm\:a + b\sqrt{2}.\:$
This can be tested by a [radical denesting formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/124461/242) that I discovered as a teenager.

---

**Simple Denesting Rule** $\rm\ \ \ \color{blue}{subtract\ out}\ \sqrt{norm}\:,\ \ then\ \  \color{brown}{divide\ out}\ \sqrt{trace} $

Recall $\rm\: w = a + b\sqrt{n}\: $ has **norm** $\rm =\: w\:\cdot\: w' = (a + b\sqrt{n})\ \cdot\: (a - b\sqrt{n})\ =\: a^2 - n\: b^2 $

and, furthermore,  $\rm\:w\:$ has **trace** $\rm\: =\: w+w' =  (a + b\sqrt{n}) + (a - b\sqrt{n})\: =\:  2\:a$

---

Here $\:9-4\sqrt{2}\:$ has norm $= 49.\:$ $\rm\ \: \color{blue}{subtracting\ out}\ \sqrt{norm}\ = 7\ $ yields $\  2-4\sqrt{2}\:$

and this has $\rm\ \sqrt{trace}\: =\: 2,\ \ so,\ \  \ \color{brown}{dividing\ it\ out}\ $ of this yields the sqrt: $\:1-2\sqrt{2}.$

Checking we have
$\ \smash[t]{\displaystyle \left(1-2\sqrt{2}\right)^2 =\ 1+8 -4\sqrt{-3}\ =\ 9-4 \sqrt{2}}.$

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4697/242) for general radical denesting algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Maple can calculate minimal polynomials, e.g.:

> evala(Norm(convert(sqrt(9-4*sqrt(2)),RootOf) - z));

$-7+2z+z^2$

Comment: Robert, do you know why sometimes Maple gives minimal polynomials in very large degree,e.g.:
$$(z^3-15z^2+75z+64)^{54}$$