# Simplify this expression with nested radical signs

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My question is-

Simplify:

$$\frac1{\sqrt{12-2\sqrt{35}}}-\frac2{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{21}}}-\frac1{\sqrt{8+2\sqrt{15}}}$$

Comment: Your thoughts on how to begin??!

Comment: Three answers, none mine, and still no up-votes except mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align} & {}\quad \frac1{\sqrt{12-2\sqrt{35}}}-\frac2{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{21}}}-\frac1{\sqrt{8+2\sqrt{15}}}\\[10pt]
& =\frac {1}{\sqrt{ 12-2 \sqrt {35}}} \frac {\sqrt{ 12+2 \sqrt {35}}}{\sqrt{ 12+2 \sqrt {35}}}- \frac {2 }{\sqrt{ 10+2 \sqrt {21}}} \frac {\sqrt{ 10-2 \sqrt {21}}}{\sqrt{ 10-2 \sqrt {21}}}- \frac{1}{\sqrt {8+2\sqrt {15}}}\frac{\sqrt {8-2\sqrt {15}}}{\sqrt {8-2\sqrt {15}}}\\[10pt]
& =\frac {\sqrt{ 12+2 \sqrt {35}}}{2}-\frac {\sqrt{ 10-2 \sqrt {21}}}{2}-\frac {\sqrt {8-2\sqrt {15}}}{2}\\[10pt]
& =\frac {{\sqrt{ 12+2 \sqrt {35}}}- {\sqrt{ 10-2 \sqrt {21}}}- {\sqrt {8-2\sqrt {15}}}}{2}\\[10pt]
& = \frac {{{|\sqrt 5 + \sqrt 7|}}- {{|\sqrt 3 - \sqrt 7|}}- {{|\sqrt 3 - \sqrt 5|}}}{2}=\sqrt 3 
\end{align}
$$

Comment: how did you solve the numerator?

Comment: This is not correct.

Comment: I noticed, I was editing my answer @Phira.

Comment: This answer is wrong: typing the original expression into a calculator gives $1.732\dots$, but $\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5}$ is negative.

Comment: @dbaupp: I missed a sign, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Fun, I have never in my entire life been asked a question which required factorizing $a+b\sqrt{c}$ into a square this way. Probably a good sign of my lack of commutative algebra.

Comment: @Gigili: should we consider 4 cases while solving the last absolute value equality?Case 1.both the second and third absolute values are positive 2.both are negative 3.second is positive and third is negative 4.second is negative and third is  positive.

Comment: No, @meg_1997. In this case, there's no variable and you know the term should be positive. Considering the first term, it's positive so it's equal to $\sqrt 5 + \sqrt 7$. The second should be positive, therefore $\sqrt 7 - \sqrt 3$ and so on.

Comment: @Gigili: ya got it..thanks

Answer (score 5):

The general method for going from a square root expression to a polynomial equation is as follows:

Rationalize the denominators and then set your expression equal to $x$.

Now, isolate one of the square roots on one side of the equation and square everything. Repeating this will eventually remove all square roots and will give you a polynomial for $x$.
Then, use estimates for $x$ to decide which root of the polynomial is $x$.

---

In that particular case, the answer is $x=\sqrt 3$, and we can do much better by recognizing the general structure.

The rationalized expression is actually of the form:

$$\frac{\sqrt{b+c+2\sqrt{bc}}}2-\frac{\sqrt{a+c-2\sqrt{ac}}}2-\frac{\sqrt{a+b-2\sqrt{ab}}}2$$

for $a=3$, $b=5$ and $c=7$.

These are complete squares, so we get:

$$\frac 12 (\sqrt b +\sqrt c +\sqrt a-\sqrt c +\sqrt a -\sqrt b) = \sqrt a=\sqrt 3.$$

Comment: @Gigili But it is, and I am sure that you will eventually edit your answer again and pretend that you came up with it yourself. But really, be my guest after you took into account the order of the numbers 3,5,7.

Comment: Seems your answer is correct, I missed a negative sign.

Answer (score 4):

Let's follow this elementary way to work out things:

$$\frac1{\sqrt{12-2\sqrt{35}}}-\frac2{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{21}}}-\frac1{\sqrt{8+2\sqrt{15}}}= \frac1{\sqrt{({\sqrt{7}-\sqrt{5}})^2}}-\frac2{\sqrt{({\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{3}})^2}}-\frac1{\sqrt{({\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}})^2}}=\frac1{({\sqrt{7}-\sqrt{5}})}-\frac2{({\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{3}})}-\frac1{({\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}})}=$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}}{2} =\sqrt3.$$

The proof is complete.

Comment: @OP Comparing this with other answers, this shows you can do the rationalization or the "completing the square" steps in either order.

Comment: It's not a proof. Also, Posting an answer at the time you did while there were other answers with the same idea doesn't seem wise.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Rationalize the denominators:

For example:

$$\sqrt{12-2\sqrt{35}}\sqrt{12+2\sqrt{35}}=\sqrt{144-4\cdot35}=\sqrt{4}=2$$

Comment: Yes i got this but how to solve the numerator?

Comment: @meg_1997 Without any more information about how you want this to be simplified, I can only speculate that converting from a sum-of-reciprocals-of-radicals to a sum-of-radicals is the best simplification. Of course, we can't always expect every expression to reduce to something nice. (Also, I'd like to throw in that "solve" and "simplify" are completely different tasks...)

Comment: Looks like I didn't spot that the expressions under the roots had cute factorizations into squares :) The other answer makes use of this.

Answer (score 1):

If you did not notice that each radical denests via $\rm\:a+b+2\sqrt{ab}\, =\, (\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2\:$ then you could easily calculate this by using this [radical denesting formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/124461/242) that I discovered as a teenager.

---

**Simple Denesting Rule** $\rm\ \ \ \color{blue}{subtract\ out}\ \sqrt{norm}\:,\ \ then\ \  \color{brown}{divide\ out}\ \sqrt{trace} $

Recall $\rm\: w = a + b\sqrt{n}\: $ has **norm** $\rm =\: w\:\cdot\: w' = (a + b\sqrt{n})\ \cdot\: (a - b\sqrt{n})\ =\: a^2 - n\: b^2 $

and, furthermore,  $\rm\:w\:$ has **trace** $\rm\: =\: w+w' =  (a + b\sqrt{n}) + (a - b\sqrt{n})\: =\:  2\:a$

---

Here $\rm\:a\!+\!b+\sqrt{ab}\:$ has norm $\rm\:(a\!-\!b)^2.\:$ $\rm\ \color{blue}{subtracting\ out}\ \sqrt{norm}\ = a\!-\!b\ $ yields $\rm\:  2b+\sqrt{ab}\:$

and this has $\rm\ \sqrt{trace}\: =\: 2\sqrt{b},\ \ hence,\ \  \ \color{brown}{dividing\ it\ out}\ $ of this yields the sqrt: $\rm\ \sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a}.$

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4697/242) for general radical denesting algorithms.